# Linux Ubuntu and Symfony cache directory

Tags: linux, symfony, composer-php

After composer install symfony `cache:clear`, I lose permission in `app/cache` directory and I must execute `chmod 777` command again.

This should be connected with ownership of that directory or?

Comment: There is a proper solution for that: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that executing composer with your current user lets Symfony create cache-files with your user and not the www-data user (or whatever user for your webserver is configured).

Try running `composer install` / `bin/console` with your webserver's user, eg. `sudo -u www-data bin/console cache:clear` / `sudo -u www-data composer install`.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

tried to look on the side of ACL ubuntu

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache
```

In setfacl command add more "-m" option with users needed

You can found more exemple in documentation

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup